# Confing launch.json in Vscode to fire up internal gdb

Tags: c, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, permissions

I'm trying to configure launch.json in vscode in order to be able to debug my program inside the editor. I' m facing 126. The vscode documentation explains [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug), that I need to create the 10-ptrace.confe inside /etc/sysctl.d/ and append this into it :

```
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0
```

I'm getting into all of these because I don't want to run vscode  as root for a simple debug session.
The problem is that the file already exists and I don't have permission to write on it, even after using:

```
sudo chmod +w 10-ptrace.conf
```

Moreover, these value that I was supposed to write in the file is set to 1 instead of 0.
How can I overcome those difficulties and debug my C program?
Is there any better way to start the debug session that I should be trying instead?

Alternative question: 
If I run gdb via terminal, how can I plot the addresses to find the one that my program is segfaulting ? Should I be using a disassembler or something else? 
 I'm currently using radare, but my prior experience is with QtSpim. Do you have any suggestions ?

I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gdb generates assembly code that corresponds directly to your source code "optimized code"
i can suggest to try "hex editor" and edit your binary code file it's available on windows and linux.
hope that could help you

Comment: Moammed Yazid Thank you for your answer ! I will not accept your answer just yet because I would like to see what other people have to say about my question. Do you happen to know why I don't have permission to edit the 10-ptrace.conf file and how can I change that?

Comment: Because basically I am in such a position that I can debug using gdb via terminal, I can get the address where my program is segfaulting but  I can not relate it with a line in my source code. I hope that vscode would have some great features to help me but since I can not config it , since I don't have the permissions I am gonna have to reverse engineer me code. Is there any way around?